# javascript alert from linkbutton click event

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP `LinkButton` that added ID values to a `List<int>` each time it is clicked.  What I need help with is how to post an alert to the user after 20 items have been added. The user cannot add more than 20, so if a 21st item is added I need to alert them.  Here's my current code:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["mylist"] + String.Empty))
    myList = (List<int>)Session["mylist"];

//Max 20 items in MyList
if (myList.Count < 20)
{
    //Add item to list
}
else
{
    //Alert to tell user that there are 20 items selected
}
```

Comment: In your code, the validation is at server side. And you question is about client side. So, two different approach there.

Comment: I'm not real concerned about whether it's client side or server side.  Just looking for the best and most practical solution to this.  Not sure simply putting a Response.Write("javascript alert here"); seems the best way to do it.  Just looking for ideas

Comment: If you go JavaScript way as @Joe put in the answer, you have more visual e.g. using jQuery/Animation. To go asp.net way, you simply have a label that is updated probably, make the text color red

Comment: @MarkHighfield sounds like you need a client side solution... or else deal with 21 postbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a client side-script

```
        if (myList.Count < 20)
        {
            //Add item to list
        }
        else
        {
            var script = "alert(\"more than 20\");";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MoreThan20", script, true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1

Place a literal some where in your html.

```
//Max 20 items in MyList
if (myList.Count < 20)
{
   //Add item to list
   literal1.Text="<script>alert("your message");</script>";
}
```

### Approach 2

Put a hidden field on your html.
Increment it by 1 every time you add new item
And in java-script check for the max value
If value reached alert your message.